# Can I say "where I expect to use them for certain"?

Tags: grammaticality

I am correcting a document where a sentence like "Where we expect to use them for certain" appears. From my point of view, the word *certain* implies, well, certainty, while the word *expect* implies uncertainty and I don't think they should be used in the same sentence.

Comment: More context would help. What things are expected to be used for certain? Does the sentence continue? (But it does sound to me that "for certain" is somewhere between redundant and misleading.)

Comment: It's similar to "We certainly expect to use them". In that case it is the expectation that is certain rather than the use.

Comment: Normally you could just substitute *sure* for *certain* there. The way you have it is more colloquial and may be too informal for your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly use this phrasing without issue:

> We certainly expect to use them

Where there is a modifier, `certain`, on your expectation. The fact that the two words have partly contradictory meanings is not a problem for your sentence, and does not change its meaning. If you feel like the contradiction is ugly, then feel free to adjust it to whatever is aesthetically pleasing to you, but it would not be a correction (just a change).